# The view pages.views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

please I'd really appreciate that  anyone in the forum can  give to me a hint with this issue in my app "pages" I do not know where is the issue, I have this error  **The view pages.views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**
Thanks in advance.

```
├── PagesProject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── pages
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── static
│   ├── logo.jpg
│   ├── main.css
│   └── top_banner.png
└── templates
    ├── 404.html
    ├── base.html
    ├── contact.html
    └── page.html
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Page
from .forms import ContactForm
    
def contact(request):
        submitted = False
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form: ContactForm = ContactForm(request.Post)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                # assert False
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact?submitted=True')
            else:
                form = ContactForm()
                if 'submitted' in request.GET:
                    submitted = True
    
            return render(request, 'contact.html',
                          {'form': form, 'page_list': Page.objects.all(), 'submitted': submitted})
```

contact.html

```
{% extends "page.html" %}
{% block title %}Contact Us{% endblock title %}


{% block content %}
<h1>contact Us</h1>

    {% if submmited %}
        <p class="success">
            Your message was submitted successfully. Thank you
        </p>
    {% else %}
    <form  action="" method="post" novalidate>
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        {% csrf_token %}
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

page.html

```
{##./templates/page.html#}
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block title %}
    {{ title }}
    {% endblock title %}

{% block sidebar %}
    {% for page in page_list %}
    <li>
    <a href="{{ page.permalink }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock sidebar %}

{% block content %}
    {% autoescape off %}

        {{ content }}
    {% endautoescape off %}
    <p>
    Page last updated: {{ last_updated| date:"D d F Y" }}
    </p>
{% endblock content %}
```

forms.py

```
# pages/forms.py
from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    yourname = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Your Name')
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False, label='Your e-mail address')
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.index, {'pagename': ''}, name='home'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('<str:pagename>', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

base.html

```
<aside id="leftsidebar">
        <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            {% block sidebar %}
            <li>Menu 1</li>
            <li>Menu 2</li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
            {% endblock sidebar %}
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
```

Comment: Your view does not return anything for a GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments your view does not return anything if the request is not a POST request.
I think that most important pieces of code are here but some re-indentation of your view code is needed to solve this.

```py
def contact(request):
        submitted = False
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form: ContactForm = ContactForm(request.Post)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                # assert False
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact?submitted=True')
        form = ContactForm()
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True
        return render(request, 'contact.html',
                          {'form': form, 'page_list': Page.objects.all(), 'submitted': submitted})
```

Comment: "re-inditation" of course, very thank you Sir.